# Mostrar todas las tags del producto separadas por coma

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

He creado una acción para que en la página de cada producto muestre unas etiquetas llamadas "artistas"

```
<?php
// Incluir etiqueta de artistas

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', "add_artist_term", 7 );
function add_artist_term() {
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'artistas');
    if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms)) { ?>
<div class="artist-term-title"><p><strong>Artista:  <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_term_link($terms[0])); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($terms[0]->name); ?></a></strong></div>
    <?php }
}
```

Funciona bien en el caso de que solo sea una etiqueta, pero cuando hay más sólo muestra la primera. ¿Cómo podría modificar el código para que me de varios resultados separados por coma.

Muchas gracias de antemano y un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Principalmente el problema se encuentra en que estás imprimiendo únicamente el primer elemento de la variable `$terms`. El siguiente código resuelve ese problema usando un `foreach`.

```
<?php

    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', "add_artist_term", 7 );

    function add_artist_term() {
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'artistas');
    }

    if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms)) : ?> // Comporbar si hay errores

        <div class="artist-term-title"><p>

        <?php foreach ($terms as $term) : ?> <!-- Imprimir el siguiente HTML por cada $term -->

            <strong>Artista:  <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_term_link($term)); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($term->name); ?></a></strong>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

        </p></div>

    <?php endif;

// ...
```

> **Nota**: En este código se imprime la palabra "Artista: " tantas veces
>   como artisas haya, para modificarlo o realizar cualquier cambio, tan
>   solo tienes que subir encima del `foreach` lo que quieres que se
>   muestre una vez, y dentro del `foreach` lo que quieres que se muestre
>   por cada artista.